# Writing a custom winston-transport: why to emit logged event?

Tags: node.js, winston

I'm working on a custom winston transport; documentation (cut&paste follows) is crystal clear...

```
class CustomTransport extends Transport {
  log(info, callback) {
    setImmediate(() => {
      this.emit('logged', info);
    });

    // Perform the writing to the remote service

    callback();
  }
};
```

... but, **which is the meaning of `this.emit('logged', info);` and why in a `setImmediate`?**

1. I would have said that calling the `callback` was enough to let the caller know that *writing operation* have been performed,
2. we could say that `setImmediate` is required to fire the event **after** IO handlers in Node.js event loop, but there is absolutely no guarantee that next IO loop is enough for my custom write to be finished, so
3. why to fire something called `'logged'` actually **before** the *write operation* rather than fire something called `'logging'`?

I asked the same thing [to the maintainers](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston-transport/issues/61), but the result was... tumbleweeds.

Can somebody revel me the *secrets* behind that mysterious event?

Answer (score 1):

Transports can listen to the `logged` event.

```
const transport = new CustomTransport();
transport.on('logged', (info) => {
  // Verification that log was called on your transport
  console.log(`Logging! It's happening!`, info);
});
```

If no transports are listening to that event, then it's useless.

I would emit the event just in case anyone is listening.

I checked winston's roadmap and in version `3.3.0` the `"logged"` event will be emitted automatically by `winston-transport`.

Answer (score 0):

Tired by the silence I did a test with a custom winston transport which does not fire the `logged` event: I wrote 3GB logs with 30,000,000 `logger.info` calls and I had no problems, neither the application grown by a single byte of memory usage.

My conclusion is: firing that event is completely useless.

Comment: Thanks - I was also wondering what was up with that line.

Comment: Did you get your custom transport to work? I am unable to do so. It funnily works only once.

Comment: Hi @Claim https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston-rotating-file this is just a POC but should work

Comment: Thanks! Did you have issues with the `log` method of your custom transport being called only once - I mean the `callback` method? https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/issues/2186 I can't wrap my mind around it...maybe you could have a look please?